# how to filter a numbers list in Python 3 inside a loop & change list length

Tags: python, list, loops, filter, python-3.x

Using PYTHON 3. I want to create a new list (floating numbers) inside a LOOP, without to change list's name, which will cut all the negative or zero elements, eventually changing its length. Who is the fastest way to do that? I have been lost trying to do the last days...

(UPDATE)

**an example:**

```
import math

l= [0.]*10

for i in range(1,10):

l[i] = math.sin(i)

l = [x for  x in l if x > 0]

print(i, l[i])
```

still is not working...

Comment: I think you need to state your problem better because "still not working" is not very useful. Beside, if you create a list with 10 elements, remove some of them during the filtering and then still try to access the 10th element, yes, that's "not going to work".

Answer (score 3):

One way I can give you:

```
new_list = [x for x in yourlist if not x <= 0 ]
```

I tried like:

```
>>> yourlist = [1, -2 , 0 , 3.9 , 4 , -5.8, -3.0 ]
>>> new_list = [x for x in yourlist if not x <= 0 ] 
>>> print new_list
[1, 3.9, 4]
```

**EDIT:**

Second method:

```
L = [1, -2 , 0 , 3.9 , 4 , -5.8, -3.0 ]
out = []
for i in L[:]:
 if i > 0:
  out.append(i)

print out
```

**EDIT2:**
As you commented to my answer, may be you need this:
Third way:

```
L = [1, -2 , 0 , 3.9 , 4 , -5.8, -3.0 ]
for obj in L[:]:
 if obj <= 0:
  del L[L.index(obj)]

print L
```

**EDIT3**  Error in your *(UPDATED)* code

In your code:

```
import math
l= [0.]*10

for i in range(1,10):
 l[i] = math.sin(i)

l = [x for  x in l if x > 0]
print(i, l[i])
```

You got `IndexError` at this `print(i, l[i])` line. because after `for-loop` value of `i` becomes `9`. and before print statement you delete some elements from list `l = [x for  x in l if x > 0]` so size of list `l` shrieked to less then  < value of `i`. and in `print(i, l[i])` you are trying to index at `i`th location that is wrong!

What do you want? If you want to print last element in list do like this:

```
print(i, l[len(l)-1])
```

Comment: Why `not x <= 0` instead of `x > 0`, is it faster?

Comment: I need the name of the list inside the LOOP to not change, any idea?

Comment: Check here its a good link: http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm ,,,It may be possible give me some time.

Comment: @user1972847 check my third answer, let me know If you need something else I am enjoying learning Python :)

Comment: the EDIT2 is working as itself , BUT unfortunately I am inside a LOOP, and I get the error:
IndexError: list index out of range
...
I have an example in the beginning ...

Comment: @user1972847 ` IndexError` because of my code? or in the code you just updated in your Question \?

Comment: @user1972847 your `indexError` is due to `print(i, l[i])` because after for loop `i` became `9` and in list iteration `l = [x for  x in l if x > 0]` you delete some elements from `l`. so `l` length `< 9`. But in `print(i, l[i])` you are trying to index at `9th` location. That the problem

Comment: thank you so much for that! ... is any way to avoid this error?

Comment: @user1972847 Yes. check condition `i < len(l)`

Comment: so easy! ... thank for your explanation and your time to help me!

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [i for i in my_list if i>0]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to easily filter elements from an iterable:

```
output = [i for i in input if i > 0]
```

or:

```
output = filter(lambda i: i > 0, input)
```

Note that [`filter(function, iterable)`][1] returns an iterator, so just do something like `output = list(output)` if you need a list object.

Comment: thank you all! ... but because I am inside a LOOP, the name of the list must be not change!, so I if: ListNew=[i for i in ListOld if i > 0] please, what I should to? ListNew=ListOld? this is not working... I am bit confused...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a list `l = [-2, -1.4, 0, 1, 2.2, 3]`

First method is to simply use list comprehension, and set the name of the list to refer to the new list created.

```
l = [i for i in l if i > 0]
```

An other method would be to loop through a copy of the list, and remove elements being smaller than or equal to 0:

```
for i in l[:]:
    if i <= 0:
        l.remove(i)
```

Either way the result is `[1, 2.2, 3]`

---

**EDIT** to your update:

```
import math
l = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    v = math.sin(i)
    if v > 0:
        l.append(i)

for v in l:
    print(v)
```

Will leave out all the numbers with 0 or negative sin, resulting into:

```
0.841470984808
0.909297426826
0.14112000806
0.656986598719
0.989358246623
0.412118485242
```

---

**EDIT2** if you also need the original number, I'd use **dictionary**:

```
import math
d = {}
for i in range(1, 10):
    v = math.sin(i)
    if v > 0:
        d[i] = v

for k in d:
    print(k, d[k])
```

Or **tuples**:

```
import math
l = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    v = math.sin(i)
    if v > 0:
        l.append((i, v))

for t in l:
    print(t[0], t[1])
```

This will result into:

```
1 0.8414709848078965
2 0.9092974268256817
3 0.1411200080598672
7 0.6569865987187891
8 0.9893582466233818
9 0.4121184852417566
```

Comment: both method dont work... I get an error in the next line ... maybe is the loop... I cant understand

Comment: Check my edit, I think that's what you're trying to achieve with your code. You don't need two for loops for this.

Comment: look.. the example that I wrote is inside another LOOP. v defined as [0]*10 .. but after this filter the length will be decreased. Your code works perfectly inside this small loop, but when you leave from that I need the value of v with the its new length (10->6) cause i have time variable and looping a lot of times... maybe i need to define after your code the new length of v?

Comment: `v` is just a value of an element inside the list `l`, so the length of `l` changes from 9 to 6. But you don't need the length of the list to be able to loop through it. I separated the printing action into an other loop so you can see how it works, check my **EDIT** again and also take a look at **EDIT2**. If it's still not enough for you, we really need to see more of your code to be able to understand your program better.

Comment: Mahi, I really appreciate your help, your EDIT2 code and your explanation significant helped... I will apply this idea in my code tomorrow and I will let you know. Thanks for your time and effort that you gave to help me. ( do you have any email for see the code? if I need more help, or I have to post it ? )

Comment: Well if you would like to get help from others than me, ofc. you should post it here. However if you think I'm good enough, you can contact me at `mahiproductions@gmail.com`